# Forced lowercase bibliography with biblatex in apa-style

Tags: biblatex, bibliographies, apa-style

Even when my .bib file has uppercase words, I can not preserve them when generating de bibliography page.

For example:

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{csquotes}
\usepackage[style=apa, backend=biber]{biblatex}
\DeclareLanguageMapping{english}{english-apa}
\bibliography{mybib}

\begin{document}
    This is a sample text of \textcite{Book1} and \parencite{Book2}
    \printbibliography
\end{document}
```

with this **mybib.bib** file:

```
@book{Book1,
    author = {First, Author},
    title = {The First Title. Four uppercase words},
    year = {1234}}
@book{Book2,
    author = {Second, Author},
    title = {This title is AWESOME},
    year = {2050}}
```

generates this bibliography:
[image: sample]

How can I preserve my uppercase words?

Comment: Hi and welcome, `title={{The First} {Title}. {Four} uppercase words}` should do the trick.

Comment: But, it is better to use a style which supports the format you need. Otherwise, if you need to format the entries with sentence-style capitalisation later, you'll have to edit every entry. (But if these are exceptional entries which should be capped no matter the style, then altering the entries is definitely the right thing to do.)

Comment: Great, problem solved!

Comment: Since this is specifically for `biblatex` with Biber, it's not a duplicate as marked.